# Conditional binding error extremely confused

Tags: ios, swift

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBAction func ButtonClicked(_ sender: Any) {

        print("SwagGODX")

        if let name = "bestgame.text" {

        LABEL.text = "hello" + "name"
        }

    }
    @IBOutlet weak var LABEL: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var bestgame: UITextField!
}
```

For the conditional binding `if let name = "bestgame.text"` it shows with the error:

> "Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'string'

I am a COMPLETE NOOB and was following a tutorial but for some reason it works for the instructor but not me. If anybody could explain it like I'm five I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

You have `"bestgame.text"` in quotes. You are telling the compiler to assign the string constant `"bestgame.text"`. That is not an optional. Get rid of the quotes:

```
if let name = bestgame.text {
    label.text = "hello" + name
}
```

(Note that you also should not have quotes around `name` in the assignment to label.text. I fixed that too in the code snippet above.)

Also note that variable names should start with lower case letters and use "camel case" (where each word in a compound word starts with a capital, like `thisIsMyLabel`.) I changed the name of your outlet from `LABEL` to `label`. You should change the declaration to match.

You might also want to make sure that name isn't an empty string:

```
if let name = bestgame.text, 
  !name.isEmpty {
    label.text = "hello" + name
}
```